# How can I stop C# console application closing after correct pin entered and after three attemps?

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie and as an exercise, have to create an application that will allow the user 3 attempts to enter their pin correctly. The issue I am having is that once the correct pin is entered, the application shuts down. The same happens after the third attempt. So the "Correct Pin" and "Goodbye" don't actually print out first. Here's what I have at the moment. Thanks.

```
        int pin = 2456;

        int attempts = 1;


        bool correctPin = false;

        while (attempts <= 3 && correctPin == false)
        {

            //Ask user to enter pin
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your pin");
            //read what user types
            string guess = Console.ReadLine();
            int number1 = int.Parse(guess);
            attempts++;

            //if correct pin entered
            if (number1 == pin)
            {

                correctPin = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Correct Pin");
            }

             //if incorrect pin entered

            else if (number1 != pin)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Pin");
            }
            else if (attempts > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");

            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside the loop you can put a:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

statement to prevent the program from exiting

It would be good, however, to at least give the user a clue that the application is waiting by writing something like "Press Enter to Exit..." to the console

Comment: Thanks! I had tried Console.ReadLine(); but didn't realise until now that it had to be outside the loop to work the way I wanted, makes sense though.

Answer (score 0):

The console window is closing since there is nothing else left to do. You should put `Console.Readline()` at the end.

Also, you should put `Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");` out of the if statement, just above the Readline().

Comment: Thanks. The former statement worked. However, I if I put the Console.WriteLine("Goodbye") above the Console.Readline(); it didn't work for me. I switched them around though so outside the loop it's the below and it worked. Cheers :)
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");

Comment: Yes, by out of the statement I meant out of the if AND while :)